# use wordpress only as a cms for non-wordpress made webpage

Tags: html, wordpress, web, content-management-system

Hoping someone can help me. I have built myself a webpage and now i need a CMS for it .

The webpage is made by me entirely (not a WordPress theme or anything),  the question is can WordPress be used for it as a CMS only and how? If not what is the best way to "bind" CMS to my webpage?

Thanks

Comment: You can create a directory for wordpress in your website or you can try building a template that is what you want  in your page only , make wordpress take it as a template and use that template on a wordpress page, I guess it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress is a opensource and freely available platform where you can build your own website by using their themes as well as you can create your own theme or child theme.

You first need to understood your requirement and then decide to use any available theme or creates your own new theme. If you want to use your own webpage which you have created then create a new theme and use that code in new theme.

For creating a new theme please chek below link.

http://www.wpexplorer.com/create-wordpress-theme-html-1/

https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Answer (score 0):

You can, look at this link 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Here you will find an explanation on how to build a wordpress theme, i suggest you turn your webpage into a theme and then use wordpress as CMS.
It may take some work but in the future you will be thankful you did it.